# when copy node js custom error class super Error variable is gone

Tags: node.js

I have a custom Err class that **extends** from Error class. all thing was good until I copy an instance of Err class. the super's variables of copied instance are undefined!

here is my code:

```js
class Err extends Error {
  constructor(code, msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.code = code;
  }
}

const error = new Err(404, 'error message');

console.log(error);
/* { Error: error message
    at repl:1:15
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:332:29)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:415:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:642:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:308:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:656:8) code: 404 }
*/

const copy = { ...error };

console.log(copy);
// { code: 404 }
// where is error.stack and error.name?
```

### SOLUTION:

Change copy method to this

```
const copy= { ...error };
copy.name = error.name;
copy.message = error.message;
copy.stack = error.stack;
```

tanks [PA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30447/pa).

**if any one has a better solution tell it to me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `copy = { ...error };`

(1) the `{}` object literal operator, creates a new Object, not a new Err object,

and

(2) the `...` or spread properties operator, for object literals, just copies the provided object **own enumerable properties** onto your new object.

To clone any javascript class instance with a perfect copy of properties, methods, getters/setters, non-enumerable properties, etc, ina a generic code is **almost impossible**. You may create your own copy/clone code for your particular case, with a combination of `Object.assign()` / `Object.getPrototype()` and custom tuning for inherited properties and internal classes.

Comment: how can i have both? i want to have error stack on copy